# Добавить новый элемент в LinearLayout

Tags: android

Простой вопрос. Как добавить новый элемент в `LinearLayout`, в определённое место, **между созданными ранее** виджетами, программно? Понятно что `AddView`, но как именно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там есть перегруженный метод - `public void addView (View child, int index)` второй параметр как раз и указывает позицию.

Comment: То есть вставляемый элемент будет идти после указанного виджета (id)?

Comment: нет. После того, как виджет будет добавлен, он будет в указанной позиции. А элемент, который был там, будет подвинут ниже.

Comment: Так вставлять? Например: _LL.addView(_RL_clear,R.id.RelativeLayout_button_download_history);

Comment: А кто его знает. второй параметр - это индекс, а вот что такое `R.id.RelativeLayout_button_download_history` -я не знаю, но подозреваю, что какая то бяка.

Comment: Короче алгоритм следующий, берешь свой леяут, у него вызываешь метод, который вернет своих чайлдов, смотришь каким идет предыдущий, берешь его ид и вставляешь в метод addView.

Comment: или еще проще, посчитай сколько раз ты уже вызвал метод addView, отними 1 и вставляй этот номер

Answer (score 0):

Простой ответ. Перетащить мышкой в редакторе хмл.

Comment: Не не вариант, нужно программно.